# how to add names/tags to JSON data before encoding

Tags: php, json

I'm quite new to working with JSON.

My current script outputs the following JSON:-

```
{"comments":[[17.9775280899,"2011-09-28 14:38:41","admin","1","2","http:\/\/www.example.com\/members\/admin\/","http:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/avatars\/1\/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg","admin"],
[0.749063670412,"2011-09-28 14:43:11","admin","1","3","http:\/\/www.example.com\/members\/admin\/","http:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/avatars\/1\/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg","admin"],
[36.329588015,"2011-10-06 14:15:12","admin","1","10","http:\/\/www.example.com\/members\/admin\/","http:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/avatars\/1\/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg","admin"]]}
```

However I would like to add a name/tag to each individual piece of data e.g. 'leftPercent', 'timestamp', 'username' etc.

This is the relevant part of my script:

First I get the data from the database...

```
$sQuery = "
    select cp_comments.*,users.user_login, users.user_url, users.display_name, users.ID as avatar

     from ".$wpdb->prefix."cp_comments cp_comments
        left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users users on users.ID=cp_comments.uid
        where songid='$id'
        order by cp_comments.id asc
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I do some custom formatting on the data. (There will be other items added later, for now it is just comments.

```
$output = array(        
    "comments" => array()
);


while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {           
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "playtime" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'playtime' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) / $duration * 100;
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] == "avatar" )
        {
            /* Special output to render Avatar by user id */
            $row[] = commentplayer_get_user_avatar($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]);
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }

    $output['comments'][] = $row;
}
```

And finally I encode the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

What part am I missing?  I'm sure this is very simple.  Thanks all.

Comment: Create an associative array instead of a numerical one, and set the "tag/names" as keys.

Comment: i'm afraid i'm not quite sure how to do this. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Just alter the data before encoding it.

Comment: Thanks jack... That is exactly what I need help with.  If someone could give me an example of how to modify the data in the manner described that would be fantastic.

Comment: Hello mate, don't take this the wrong way as it's sound advice, but youve just given away that youre working on a certain domain which isnt launched also youve given away that it WP and that it's got a certain DB structure, I've edited the domain out for u..

Comment: whoops! seriously stupid of me I clearly wasn't thinking! Huge thanks for editing it for me mate! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `$aColumns[$i]` corresponds to the name column from a database query, then try this

```
$output = array(

    "comments" => array()
);


while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{

    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {

        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "playtime" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'playtime' column */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) / $duration * 100;
        }


        else if ( $aColumns[$i] == "avatar" )
        {
            /* Special output to render Avatar by user id */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = commentplayer_get_user_avatar($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]);
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }


    $output['comments'][] = $row;



}
```

I changed `$row[]` to `$row[$aColumns[$i]]`